# How to create dynamically findViewById() for a class

Tags: java, android

I want to make a game and I need the make a class which I will send the ID of ImageView and the class create an object with this id so I can run all class function on the ImageView.

**Example :**

Let's say I have 3 ImageView's with id's M1,M2 and M3.
I want to make a class named "myimg", So when I call "myimg(M1)" the class creates an object that will effect the "ImageView" with ID M1 and run all functions of the class "myimg" on M1.

```
public class myimg{

        private ImageView m;

        myimg(int id){
            m = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id...)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch this.

```
public class MyImage {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private ViewGroup mViewGroup;

    public MyImage(Activity activity) {
       mActivity = activity;
    }

    public MyImage(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       mViewGroup = viewGroup;
    }

    public MyImage(Activity activity,int id) {
       mActivity = activity;
       mImageView = createViewById(id);
    }

    public MyImage(ViewGroup viewGroup,int id) {
       mViewGroup = viewGroup;
       mImageView = createViewById(id);
    }

    public ImageView createViewById(int id) {
        if (mActivity != null) {
            ImageView view = mAcitivity.findViewById(id);
            if (view == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Can't find resource with id = " + id);
            return view;
        }
        if (mViewGroup != null) {
            ImageView view = mViewGroup.findViewById(id);
            if (view == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Can't find resource with id = " + id);
            return view;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't create view. Looks like a parent null.");
    }
}
```

#### Using

```
public void onCreate(...) {
    MyImage image = new MyImage(this,R.id.my_image);
    //Or
    MyImage image = new MyImage(this);
    image.createViewById(R.id.myImage);
}
```

---

> **Note :** If you will be use MyImage class you should be confident that ViewGroup(LinearLayout, etc.) not be null.

Answer (score 0):

If id value is R.id.XXXX then it will work:

```
 myimg(int id){
        m = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
    }
```

Id id is a String, and its value is the XXXX in R.id.XXXX then it will work:

```
myimg(String res) {
  int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(res ,"id",getActivity().getPackageName());
  m = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myimg{

    ImageView m1,m2,m3 ;
    ImageView chosenImageID ;

    m1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    m2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    m3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    public ImageView myimg(ImageView id){
        chosenImageID = id;
        if(chosenImageID == m1)
            return m1;
        else if(chosenImageID == m2)
            return m2;
        else
            return m3;
    }
}
```

You can use myimg(ImageView) to determine your chosen imageView for your other methods.